# using keyword with private member assignment to manage IDisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable

I was reading [Stephen Cleary's blog post about cancellation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/03/cancellation-2-requesting-cancellation.html), and I saw something I haven't seen before in the following code snippet.

```
Constructor() => CancelButton.Enabled = false;

private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;

async void StartButton_Click(..)
{
    StartButton.Enabled = false;
    CancelButton.Enabled = true;

    // Create a CTS for manual cancellation requests.
    using var cts = _cts = new();

    try
    {
        // Pass the token for that CTS to lower-level code.
        await DoSomethingAsync(_cts.Token);
        .. // Display success in UI.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        .. // Display error in UI.
    }
    finally
    {
        StartButton.Enabled = true;
        CancelButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}

async void CancelButton_Click(..)
{
    // Manually cancel the CTS.
    _cts!.Cancel();
}
```

Particularly, the `using var cts = _cts = new();` line.

Is the `using` managing the disposal of the private member as well as the local variable?

Why assign the local variable if it's not used anywhere?

What is going on here?

Comment: It calls `Dispose()` on the value of the local variable - but it's *also* assigned to the field.

Comment: So, when is `Dispose()` called in this case? When both `cts` and `_cts` are out of scope?

Comment: @brent.reynolds See my answer. `_cts` is never directly disposed (and it would not be safe to do so if you look at the code snippets, because it can get overwritten by another thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because you can't do this:

```
using _cts = new();
```

That will give a compile error, "Identifier expected".

So he's introduced a local variable which will be disposed at the end of the method:

```
using var cts = _cts = new();
```

Now it will compile, and `cts` will be disposed (NOTE: it does NOT dispose `_cts`; it will only dispose the introduced local variable, `cts`).

He wanted to initialise a field, `_cts`, and have the created object automatically disposed at the end of the method, and this is a simple way to do so.

This would be the alternative way of writing it:

```
_cts = new();
using var cts = _cts;
```

An alternative way of writing this that might look less weird is to have a method that initialises `_cts` and returns it:

```
CancellationTokenSource initialiseCancellationToken()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _cts = cts;
    return cts;
}
```

Then you'd write the less suprising:

```
using var cts = initialiseCancellationToken();
```

You pays yer money and you makes yer choice!

Note: You might be tempted to write this:

```
CancellationTokenSource initialiseCancellationToken()
{
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    return _cts;
}
```

But that has a subtle race condition! Can you spot it (assuming that `initialiseCancellationToken()` can be called by multiple threads simultaneously)?

Comment: While you're correct that `Dispose` is called on the local variable and not `_cts`, these do of course refer to the same object, so functionally it does dispose `_cts` (as long as it's not reassigned).

Comment: @McNets That's a more complex example because the `_cts` variable can also be changed from another thread, which is what is being checked. But the underlying reason is the same - it's to simplify the `using` code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In that code snippet it does, but there's another snippet later in the linked page where `_cts` might be set to a different value from `cts`.

Comment: Yes, the code is somehow both elegant and ugly, in that it's a succinct expression of an idiom that makes sense once you understand it, but doesn't stop looking unintuitive even when you do.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely idiomatic!

Comment: Ohhhh yeah. Ok. I think I get it now. Thanks.